# RegEx - Regex for number range ignore spaces in digits

Tags: regex

I require regular expression to match for number range starting with 4, next 5 or 6 then 8 digits.

I wrote the following RegEx:

```
^.*(4[5-6][0-9]{8}).*$
```

> Examples:
> Input = 4600004785/0010
>
> > return substitute $1 = 4600004785

> Input = N°4500648235
>
> > return substitute $1 = 4500648235

But how to retrieve the same number range if the Input contains spaces between the number like:

> Input = N° 45 00 64 82 35
>
> > substitute = 4500648235

I found a RegEx to remove the spaces between digits but i don't understand how to mix both

```
(\d)(?= \d)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please specify tool/lang you're using. With basic regex you'd probably need to [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) each digit surrounded by the [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) spaces. Something like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/E9d4qX/1).

Comment: If format is consistent with your sample, try substitute [`^.*?(4[56]) ?(\d\d) ?(\d\d) ?(\d\d) ?(\d\d).*$` with `$1$2$3$4$5`](https://regex101.com/r/wpy78F/1) (optional space after each `dd`)

Comment: Hello @bobblebubble how can i manage this case :
Input = N° 450 064 82 35
The place of the space could be anywhere inside the digit :(

Sorry : ^.*?(4) ?([56]) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d).*$ is correct ;)

Comment: Looks like you got it solved, feel free to post answer yourself that solved it. It's always good to mention what tool/lang you're using and better describing the task/goal. Things can sometimes be solved easier without regex or a combination of regex and other functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
^.*?(4) ?([56]) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d) ?(\d).*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/64kPOU/1).